# BootStrap 3 building main page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to create the main page, with a navtop, a nav left side and content in middle. The menu and the navtop should be fixed on the screen. Only the content should be scrollable.

When the menu is expanded, the content is pushed to the right, without element reordering inside, just pushed as it is on the right, so a part of the content on the right will be hidden out-out the screen while a menu is expanded.

Here are images to illustrate:

[Collapsed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQZTp.png)

[Expanded menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOeL1.png)

(Sorry I can't embed images because of my low reputation)

So when I hover the menu, it expands and pushes the content to the right. When a mouse is out the menu, it collapses and only shows icons.

I nearly managed to do this, but I can't give you the code, it's professional.

I'm the beginner in CSS, it's hard for me I tried a lot but no way to managed to build this page.

I put the menu and the content on `float: left`, but when I load a new page, the content is on the menu, so I can't click on menu icons anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this demo,

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this that should work how you want if I understood your post correctly. It uses a few lines of Jquery for the animation when you hover over the side navigation menu. The icons  and text are just placeholders

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sidenav").hover(function(){
    $(".hidetext").stop(true).toggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.sidenav-wrapper {
  margin-top: 51px;
}

.sidenav {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

.sidenav span {
  font-size: 45px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidenav span .hidetext {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  float: right;
  display: none; /* Changes to inline-block on hover */
}

.main-content {
  margin-top: 51px;
  margin-left: 89px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topnav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topnav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="sidenav-wrapper">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home home" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#"><p class="hidetext">Home</p></a></span>
    <br>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"><a href="#"><p class="hidetext">Options</p></a></span></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>Stuff on the right of side navigation bar</p>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```